# Populating dynamic images in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, sdwebimage

I am trying to make an app with an anonymous feed exactly like Instagram. I have used AFNetworking to download the JSON data and SDWebImage to add and cache the images.

As I am loading variable size images I want the table view cell to automatically adjust its height.

Now the problem is when the app loads up, image is not displayed properly but after I scroll down and scroll back to the same cell, image adjusts itself exactly the way I want but there is always a space above and below the image.

### Before scrolling

---

[image]

### After Scrolling Back

---

[image]

Following are the UIImage view's constraints :

1. Trailing space to superview : 0
2. Leading space to superview : 0
3. Top space: 8
4. bottom space :8
5. Intrinsic size is set to placeholder and content mode to Aspect Fit.

Here's my code of ViewDidLoad method:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    feedList = NSMutableArray() 

    self.feedTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.feedTable.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0

    var connection :  CommunicationManager! = CommunicationManager()

    //initiate a connection and load feed data
    connection.getFeedData( { (response, error) -> Void in

        if(response != nil){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.feedList = response
                self.feedTable.hidden = false
                self.feedTable.reloadData()
            })

        }

}
```

TableView's CellForRowAtIndex:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell


    let feedData : NSDictionary! = feedList[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    let imgURL : NSURL! = NSURL(string: feedData.valueForKey("image_name") as! String)
    cell.feedImage.sd_setImageWithURL(imgURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "LoadingImage"))

    return cell
}
```

I tried all my best to solve this problem but was unable to make it work. Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this issue using storyboard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call layoutIfneeded method : Use following code :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId"];

[cell.nImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    cell.widthConst.constant = image.size.width;
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell layoutSubviews];

}];

return cell;
```

}

If you want dynamic width then you need to add fixed width constraint and update it in block.

refer screenshots [image] [image: image2]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can you please explain what is cell.widthConst.constant
Because I am not getting any auto suggestions for widthConst

Comment: widthConst is constant width constraint of imageview. As I said if you want to set width of image view equal to downloded image's width then you can use this constraints outlet to modify width

Comment: When I added constraints like trailing and leading space to 0, width will be calculated automatically right?

Comment: if you check it properly for different size images you will get some strange output for width . You can check that. Its not working in my case so i have added this constraint. I think cells height get calculated again because of those tableview properties but there is no provision to update image width. Try it n let me know, if its working in your case or not.

Comment: I added a width constraint as you said, but it is now giving an error message that "Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want"

Comment: while adding constraints refer 2nd screen shot in answer. You have to remove leading and trailing constraints, and add make that image horizontally center in container.

Comment: give your xib i'll fix it

Comment: have you tried anything else, because its working properly, i don't know what is going wrong in your case.

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong..
How should I send you the xib file?

Comment: in your question you can add link from where i can download it.... you can use dropbox link

Comment: please find the xib file here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rowmuvn4hdc7z7h/AABcl8lnguI1rpQvr2Qz5Uzta?dl=0

Comment: use this demo https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3b81kf2llogzs7/DynamicHeightImage.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the demo. But I have variable size images, so i was giving trailing and leading constraints because of which images would then automatically adjust their height. Which is by the way happening when I scroll back to the same cell. In the demo lets say I have an image of size 720 * 720 and it won't fit properly on iPhone 4s or 5.

Comment: ok then you have to do some changes for width .... but I think my demo will  work for height in any device .

Comment: Can you please suggest what should I do?